How do I set the background to an image in three.js?
Sorry, I'm new to three.js and I know (most) of the basics but somehow I don't know how to set the background image. I need to set the background image to a space-themed background, because in my website I'm trying to make different worlds for the game. But, the background is just black. I want it to be an image, not a color. I want it to be an image because a plain color for the background of a space-themed website would look lame.
here's my code:
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {OrbitControls} from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import stars from '../homepage folder/Unknown.jpeg';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
const canvas = document.querySelector(".webgl");
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {canvas} );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setAnimationLoop( animate );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 5, 5, 5 );
const material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );
const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material1 );
scene.add( cube1 );
const geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 5, 5, 5 );
const material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );
scene.add( cube2 );
const geometry3 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 5, 5, 5 );
const material3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube3 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry3, material3 );
scene.add( cube3 );

const planeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 3, 100);
const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff});
const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
scene.add(plane);

const orbit = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
orbit.update();

const loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
const skyboxTexture = loader.load([
stars,
stars,
stars,
stars,
stars,
stars
]);
scene.background = skyboxTexture;

cube1.position.y = 10;
cube1.position.z = -10;
cube2.position.y = 5;
cube2.position.z = -10;
cube3.position.y = 0;
cube3.position.z = -10;

plane.position.y = -2;

camera.position.z = 20;
camera.position.y = 30;

camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)

function animate() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    cube1.rotation.y += 0.02;
    cube2.rotation.y += 0.02;
    cube3.rotation.y += 0.02;
    cube1.rotation.x += 0.02;
    cube2.rotation.x += 0.02;
    cube3.rotation.x += 0.02;
    cube1.rotation.z += 0.02;
    cube2.rotation.z += 0.02;
    cube3.rotation.z += 0.02;
}


This question is similar to: Changing three.js background to transparent or other color. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't think this path with space is correct... import stars from '../homepage folder/Unknown.jpeg';

i changed the folder name to something without spaces and changed my code. Somethings still not working? im so confused

if the file directory was wrong, then it would display an error, would it not?

@massiveFatty372 Could you paste in your post your folder tree?

oh-nevermind! I got it! I just forgot to change one of the letters in the file directory! Thank you so much for helping!

The background in the 3D world is understood slightly differently. The 3D scene fills the space and its contents are projected onto the 2D screen using a projection matrix. Classical way of background, like a texture or image, can be set in two ways: the first is a flat texture covering the entire screen using the scene.background property, and the second, more suitable in your case (move camera then you will see), is a cube (skybox) filled with textures on each of its sides.
Other ways, what you can consider are:

Equirectangular Texture
Video Texture
HDR Texture
Custom Shader BG Texture






*{margin:0}
<script type="importmap">
  {
"imports": {
  "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.169.0/build/three.module.js",
  "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.169.0/examples/jsm/"
}
  }
</script>

<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 20;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const bgTexture = textureLoader.load('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/refs/heads/dev/examples/textures/planets/moon_1024.jpg');
scene.background = bgTexture;

const coneRadius = 5;
const coneHeight = 10;

const coneG = new THREE.ConeGeometry(coneRadius, coneHeight, 16);
const coneM = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00,
    wireframe: true
});
const cone = new THREE.Mesh(coneG, coneM);

scene.add(cone);

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;

let rotationSpeedY = 0.005;
let groupRotationY = 0;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    groupRotationY += rotationSpeedY;
    cone.rotation.set(0, groupRotationY, 0);

    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function resizeView() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeView);

animate();

</script>



2.


*{margin:0}
 <script type="importmap">
      {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.169.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.169.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
      }
    </script>

    <script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 20;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
const skyboxTexture = loader.load([
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/refs/heads/dev/examples/textures/cube/MilkyWay/dark-s_px.jpg', // P X
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/refs/heads/dev/examples/textures/cube/MilkyWay/dark-s_nx.jpg', // N X
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/refs/heads/dev/examples/textures/cube/MilkyWay/dark-s_py.jpg', // P Y
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/refs/heads/dev/examples/textures/cube/MilkyWay/dark-s_ny.jpg', // N Y
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/refs/heads/dev/examples/textures/cube/MilkyWay/dark-s_pz.jpg', // P Z
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/refs/heads/dev/examples/textures/cube/MilkyWay/dark-s_nz.jpg'  // N Z
]);

scene.background = skyboxTexture;

const coneRadius = 5;
const coneHeight = 10;

const coneG = new THREE.ConeGeometry(coneRadius, coneHeight, 16);
const coneM = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00,
    wireframe: true
});
const cone = new THREE.Mesh(coneG, coneM);

scene.add(cone);

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;

let rotationSpeedY = 0.005;
let groupRotationY = 0;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    groupRotationY += rotationSpeedY;
    cone.rotation.set(0, groupRotationY, 0);

    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function resizeView() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeView);

animate();


    </script>




I like the first one, it works perfectly. But, if I want it to look 3d, I want to use the second Strat. But, I tried the second Strat and it dosen't seem to work. Any idea why? Also, thanks so much for you time helping me.

what's weird, though is that when I copy the code above into my file, it works. but it dosent work when I use my own images

@massiveFatty372 You probably have a problem with the path to the image. Edit your post and paste the code that doesn't work there, I'll see what's wrong with it.
